# Using Python to download CSV file from 'Database Browser' Wordpress plugin

Tags: python, session, python-requests

The following code correctly provides the login credentials and submits the form to my wordpress site.

The 'requestUrl' bit seems to correctly visit the "?page=databasebrowser" page. If visiting that page in a browser, a dialog appears to download the CSV. I cannot figure out how adjust this script to save that file.

```
import requests
import csv

#This URL will be the URL that your login form points to with the "action" tag.
postLoginUrl = 'https://www.mywebsiteurl.com/wp-login.php?itsec-hb-token=manage'

loginPayload = {
    "log": "myusername",
    "pwd": "mypassword"
}

#This URL is the page you actually want to pull down with requests.
requestUrl = 'https://www.mywebsiteurl.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=databasebrowser&table=wpbss_mywebsitename_estimateform&export=CSV&_wpnonce=ecfd982f17'
getCsvPayload = {
    "table": "wpbss_mywebsitename_estimateform"
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(postLoginUrl, data=loginPayload)
    page = session.post(requestUrl, data=getCsvPayload)
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

What respons code för you get from de post requests? Maybe you need to set an header to? User-Agent  headers is often required